# change starting letter to upper case

Tags: java, string, capitalization

I am using Java where I have a string and want to make first letter of word to upper case (each word with comma seperated).

I know using `WordUtils.capitalize(str)` it is possible but what I have is as below.

```
String str = "companies,user,";
```

I know `split` and `Wordutils` will do the job, but I am looking for one-liner.

---

Output looking is one string as

```
Companies, User
^         ^^
```

### OR

```
Companies,User
^         ^
```

### and NOT

```
Companies,user
^         ^
```

Comment: Why not make a function using split and wordutils, it will be "one-liner" when using...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following in single line !:

```
String str = "companies,user,";
        str = String.valueOf(str.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1,str.indexOf(","))+
            str.substring(str.indexOf(","),str.indexOf(",") + 1) + String.valueOf(str.charAt(str.indexOf(",") + 1)).toUpperCase() + str.substring(str.indexOf(",") + 2);
```

Comment: very smart... this is testing string... what if I have abc, xyz

Comment: if you have "abc,xyz" It too will work with my code..try it. You should not use spacebar between "," though lol ;)

Comment: this only works for the first two words in the comma-separated list. Any other word will not be capitalized.

Comment: @nansen: OP has not asked to apply this on the String containing more than two words..;)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply:

```
String str = "companies,user,";
String strCaps = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1);
```

**Edit**: The only way to make it a single line is to make it a method, and use the method, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "companies,user,";
    System.out.println(capitaliseEach(str));
}

static String capitaliseEach(String string)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] split = string.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        if(split[i] != null && split[i].length() >= 2)
        {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(split[i].charAt(0))).append(split[i].substring(0));
        }
        if((i + 1) < split.length)
        {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: yes, that I know. Hence I was looking for something one liner.. I have already done split and uppercase, but I don't wanted to use method. I thought there would be some pre-defined function available. though u r on track, i will accept your answer tomorrow OR later as I would still wait for this.

Answer (score 0):

Resuable Method for intiCap

```
public class YarlagaddaSireeshTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String FinalStringIs="";
        String testNames="Sireesh,Yarlagadda";
        String[] name=testNames.split(",");

        for(String nameIs :name){
        FinalStringIs+=getIntiCapString(nameIs)+","
                ;
        }
        System.out.println("Final Result "+ FinalStringIs);

    }

    public static String getIntiCapString(String param) {
        if(param != null && param.length()>0){          
            char[] charArray = param.toCharArray(); 
            charArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[0]); 
            return new String(charArray); 
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of yashwant if I write `companies,user,` what output will I hve?

Answer (score 0):

Functional languages like clojure are ideal for this. Since clojure is a jvm language you could evaluate clojure code from within java. Even as a one liner if you are desperate:

```
RT.var("clojure.core", "eval")
      .invoke(RT.var("clojure.core", "read-string")
           .invoke(
              "(clojure.string/join \", \" " +
                "(map clojure.string/capitalize " +
                  "(clojure.string/split \"companies,user,\" #\",\")))"));
```

the plain clojure version:

```
(clojure.string/join 
   ", " (map clojure.string/capitalize 
          (clojure.string/split "companies,user," #",")))
```

Honestly, you would never wanna do that! But since you are looking for a one-liner I guess it's worth the fun.